# C++ matrix destruction causes breakpoint and critical error (solution is at the end of the question)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, constructor, destructor

So I want to create a 4x4 matrix class which stores its data as a `float** m`.
I initialize it like this:

```
Matrix4f::Matrix4f()
{
    this->m = new float*[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        this->m[i] = new float[4];
        memset(this->m[i], 0, sizeof(float) * 4);
    }
}
```

And after that, I have a destructor like this:

```
Matrix4f::~Matrix4f()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        delete[] m[i];
    }

    delete[] m;
}
```

But sometimes when I use this class, this line:

```
delete[] m[i];
```

Causes a breakpoint, and it throws: `Critical error detected c0000374`
Is this the right way of initializing and deleting a 4x4 matrix?

Edit: for future readers: my problem was that I didn't override the copy constructor of the matrix, and the assignment operator (void operator=(const Matrix&). This is a problem because it is possible that a copy is made silently (like saying `Matrix4f mat = getTransformationMatrix();`, and this matrix then gets deleted at the end of the scope, releasing the same pointer as the transformation matrix has, because the pointer is copied, not the contents. So override those two functions like in the accepted answers, and it will get rid of problems like this.

Comment: The question contains insufficient detail to diagnose the issue. But more fundamentally, regular multi-dimensional arrays (such as matrices) should not be represented by pointers to pointers. Instead, use a `std::vector<double>` of length 16 (in your case), and calculate the offset based on the indices as `i + j * 4` (or `i * 4 + j`, depending on whether you want row-major or column-major representation).

Comment: Does your class follow the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Can you provide a [mcve]? Is there a reason you want to use heap allocation instead of a plain `float m[4][4];`?

Comment: The code is correct, so the error is elsewhere. You probably call a destructor of a null object.

Comment: If I use float[4][4], do I need to delete it with the code in the destructor, or will it be freed automatically?

Comment: @Andrew It will be freed automatically, so you don't need a custom destructor at all.

Comment: Following up on the comment made by @HolyBlackCat - is there some code elsewhere that silently makes a copy of a `Matrix4f` object (and then, equally silently, destroys is)? Like passing such an object as a function parameter? If so, calling that copy's destructor will very likely cause you to attempt the `delete[]` operation on something already deleted.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not entirely sure but it's possible because I wrote a Camera class and I basically just copied the java version, so there could be some bad memory management somewhere. I guess that's the case

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Just to clarify, using a plain `float m[4][4]` will not solve the rule of three issue. I guess it was not the goal of your comment.

Comment: @Damien It will solve the issue, no? Compiler-generated copy/move constructors and assignment operators will do the right thing for `float m[4][4];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned the rule of the three could be the issue. Your provided code is technical correct, however, if you copy a Matrix4f you have to reimplement the copy constructor and the overloaded assignment constructor:

```
#include <iostream>


class Matrix4f
{
public:
    Matrix4f()
        : m_data(new float*[4])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            m_data[i] = new float[4]{ 0 };
    }
    Matrix4f(const Matrix4f& source)
    {
        m_data = new float*[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            m_data[i] = new float[4]{ 0 };
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                m_data[i][j] = source.m_data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    Matrix4f& operator=(const Matrix4f& source)
    {
        if (this == &source) return *this;

        clear();
        m_data = new float*[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            m_data[i] = new float[4]{ 0 };
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                m_data[i][j] = source.m_data[i][j];
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }
    ~Matrix4f()
    {
        clear();
    }
//private:
    float**m_data;

    void clear()
    {
        if (m_data != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                delete[] m_data[i];
            }
            delete[]m_data;
        }
    }

    void print()const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                std::cout << m_data[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
};



int main()
{
    Matrix4f m1;

    m1.m_data[0][0] = m1.m_data[1][1] = m1.m_data[2][2] = m1.m_data[3][3]  = 1;

    {
        Matrix4f m2(m1);
        Matrix4f m3 = m2;

        m2.print();
        m3.print();
    }

    m1.print();
}
```

But I recommend you to use one dimensional vectors instead, its much faster and much safer.

Comment: I've already defined a copy constructor, which just allocates the m variable and then uses memcpy for every column of the matrix to copy the data, I guess its the = operator which causes the issue, but I'm gonna change it to a float m[16]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your code is fine, if and only if you corretly manage the case of copies.

You have three choices:

1. disable copy
2. shallow copy
3. deep copy

Let us discuss this choices:

1. you would need to only declare the copy constructor and the copy assigment operator delted. Now there is no way to copy objects of your class. This reduces the usefullness of the matrix-class.
2. This has no real value for its' own. Since you can achieve this by wrapping a object of type 3 into an `std::shared_ptr`.
3. There is no need for dynamic memory in this case. And even if there were, you would like to use a std::vector or something to manage the memory.
   The sane solution would be to use an `float[4][4]` as `m`.
   This would be more robust since you avoided the memory managment.

Comment: 4. Include data within matrix object (declare `m` as `float m[4][4];`). This is the only sensible approach imho.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica this would be a better version of 3.

Comment: ... with the special feature that you wouldn't even need to write the copy constructor. The default copy constructor would work fine.

Comment: ... also the default constructor and destructor would work. And since 16 `floats` are not that much to copy there is not much gained by 1 or 2. will edit my answer to give more weight to the current 3.